# On Submit add port number to URL codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

On clicking the submit button at page http://localhost:8080/Jan182017/users/add_user/ it is redirected to http://localhost/Jan182017/users/add_user/#menu1, and it displays  - This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect error message. what is the best way to add :8080 to the URL on submit, my code is as below,

Controller : users.php

```html
function add_user(){
   global $SITE;
   global $USER;
   $data = array();
   if($USER->permissions[0] == 'all' || $this->uri->segment(3)==$USER->userdetid) {
   $data['team_details']=$this->mod_users->get_team_details();
   $data['error_message'] = '';
   $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
   
   $data['action'] = 'add';
   $data['heading'] = 'Add';
   $data['row'] = new stdClass();
   $data['row'] = $this->admin_init_elements->set_post_vals($this->input->post());
   $data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';  
   $post_action = $this->input->post('action');
   $data['proofs'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array2('pr_proofs',NULL,NULL,'');
   
   if($post_action=='add' || $post_action =='update' ){
    
    $post_array = $this->input->post();
    $action = ($post_action == 'add')?'inserted':'updated';     
    $data['error_message'] = $this->mod_users->validate_user_form($this->input->post('id'));    
    if($data['error_message']=='valid'){ 
     if($_FILES['profileimage']['name']!=''){      
      $upload_val = $this->admin_init_elements->do_upload_img('profileimage',$SITE->user_profile_image_src);
      if($upload_val!='' && !is_array($upload_val)){
       $post_array['profileimage'] = $upload_val;
       if($action=='updated' && $post_array['originalprofileimage']!='' && $post_array['originalprofileimage']!= DEFAULT_IMG_NAME){
        $path = FCPATH.$SITE->user_profile_image_src;
        unlink_file($path.FOLDER_ORIGINAL.$post_array['originalprofileimage']);
        unlink_file($path.FOLDER_LARGE.$post_array['originalprofileimage']);
        unlink_file($path.FOLDER_SMALL.$post_array['originalprofileimage']);
        unlink_file($path.FOLDER_THUMB.$post_array['originalprofileimage']);
       }
      }else{
       $post_array['profileimage'] = DEFAULT_IMG_NAME;
      }      
     }
     
     $data['error_message'] = $this->mod_users->add_edit_user($post_array,$action);
     if($data['error_message'] = 'Record '.$action.' successfully'){
      $data['row'] = new stdClass();
      $data['row']->status = 1;
     }
    }else{
     $data['msg_class'] = '';  
    }
   }
   
   if($data['id']>0){
    
    $data['action'] = 'update';
    $data['heading'] = 'Edit';
    $data['row'] = $this->mod_common->get_details($data['id'],'users_details'); ;
    $data['status'] = $data['row']->status;
    $data['row']->userdetail = $this->mod_common->get_details($data['row']->userid,'users');
    
    $ucomp = $this->mod_common->get_user_comp_by_id($data['row']->userid);
    
    foreach($ucomp as $c)
    {
     $usercomp[$c['year']][$c['comp_element']] = $c['comp_value'];
     
    }
    
    $data['row']->usercomp = $usercomp;
    $uleave = $this->mod_common->get_user_leave_by_id($data['row']->userid);
    foreach($uleave as $l)
    {
     $userleave[$l['leavetype']] = $l['leavecount'];
     
    }
    $data['row']->userleave = $userleave;
    //print_r($data['row']->usercomp);die();
    $data['caddress'] = get_address1($data['row'],'1',$data['id']);
    $data['paddress'] = get_address1($data['row'],'6',$data['id']); 
    get_city_state_country_array($data,array('cityid'=>$data['paddress']->cityid));
    get_city_state_country_array1($data,array('cityid'=>$data['caddress']->cityid));
    $user_proofs = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array2('pr_user_proofs','userid',$data['row']->userid,'');
    foreach($user_proofs as $up)
    {
     $docproof[$up->documentid]['document_number'] = $up->document_number;
     $docproof[$up->documentid]['expiry_date'] = $up->expiry_date;
     $docproof[$up->documentid]['doc_file'] = $up->doc_file;
    }
    $data['docproof'] = $docproof;
    $family_profile = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array2('pr_user_family','userid',$data['row']->userid,'');
    $data['family_profile'] = $family_profile[0];
    
    $bank_details = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array2('pr_user_bank','userid',$data['row']->userid,'');
    $data['bank_details'] = $bank_details[0];
    
    
   } else 
   {
    get_city_state_country_array($data,array('cityid'=>$data['row']->cityid));
    get_city_state_country_array1($data,array('cityid'=>$data['row']->cityid));
   }
   
   
   
   
   $data['comp_elem'] = $this->mod_common->get_comp_element_by_func_level($data['row']->userdetail->departmentid,$data['row']->designation_id);
   $userlevel = 0;
   $comp_struct_elements=$this->mod_common->get_array_frontend_raw('pr_comp_elements','*','');
   $data['comp_struct_setting']=$this->mod_common->get_array_frontend('comp_struct','*','');
   
   $comp_cat = array("Standard Elements","Allowances","Deductions from Gross Salary","Variable Salary","Loans and Advances");
   foreach($comp_struct_elements as $cse)
   {
    if($cse->comp_category == 'Standard')
     $data['comp_elements2'][0][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Allowances')
     $data['comp_elements2'][1][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Deductions from Gross')
     $data['comp_elements2'][2][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Variable Salary')
     $data['comp_elements2'][3][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Loans and Advances')
     $data['comp_elements2'][4][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Other Benefits or Perks')
     $data['comp_elements2'][5][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Stocks or Shares')
     $data['comp_elements2'][6][] = $cse;
    else if($cse->comp_category == 'Direct Pay')
     $data['comp_elements2'][7][] = $cse;
    
   }
   foreach($data['comp_struct_setting'] as $comp_struct_setting)
   {
    $data['comp_struct'][] = $comp_struct_setting->optional_element;
   }
   $data['leaves'] = $this->mod_common->get_leave_types();
   $data['departments'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('department',NULL,NULL,'departmentname');
   $data['branches'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('office',NULL,NULL,'branchname');
   $data['divisions'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('divisions',NULL,NULL,'division_name');
   $data['shifts'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array2('pr_shifts',NULL,NULL,'');
   $data['roles'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('designation','status',"1' AND id > '0",'designation');
   $data['uroles']  = $this->mod_common->get_array_frontend('roles');
   $data['row']->userlevel = isset($data['row']->userlevel)?$data['row']->userlevel:0;
   $data['row']->branchid = isset($data['row']->branchid)?$data['row']->branchid:0;
   $data['row']->managerid = $this->mod_common->get_managerids($data['id']);
   $data['users'] = get_employees_above_level($data['row']->userlevel,$data['row']->branchid);
   $data['last_emp_code'] = $this->mod_users->get_last_emp_code();
   $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/add_editUser', $data,true); 
   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
   } else {
    $data['permission'] = 'Edit Profile of other users';
    $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/access_denied', $data,true); 
    $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
   }
  }
```

View : add_editUser.php

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart('users/add_user/'.$id.'#menu1', array('method'=>'post','name'=>'addEditUserForm','id'=>'addEditUserForm'));?>
       <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Personal</h3>
        
         <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1">
         
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="col-md-2" style="" class="pull-right">
          <div class="control-group col-md-11">
           <div class="controls">
             <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
              <?php $changeremove = false;
             if($row->profileimage!='' && file_exists($SITE->user_profile_image_src.FOLDER_THUMB.$row->profileimage)){
              echo img(array('src'=>$SITE->user_profile_image_src.FOLDER_THUMB.$row->profileimage,'width'=>200));
              echo form_hidden('originalprofileimage',$row->profileimage);
              $changeremove = true;
             }else{
              echo '<img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />';
             }?>
            </div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
            <div class="btn-container"> <span class="btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-upload "></i> Upload Image</span> <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
              <?php  echo form_upload(array('name'=>'profileimage','id'=>'profileimage','class'=>"default" ));?>
              </span> <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a> </div>
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10" >
          
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px" >
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
             <label >Prefix</label>
             
             <select name="prefix" class="form-control select2">
              <option value="Mr." <?=($row->prefix=='Mr.')?"selected='selected'":""?>>Mr.</option>
              <option value="Ms." <?=($row->prefix=='Ms.')?"selected='selected'":""?>>Ms.</option>
              <option value="Mrs." <?=($row->prefix=='Mrs.')?"selected='selected'":""?>>Mrs.</option>
              <option value="Dr." <?=($row->prefix=='Dr.')?"selected='selected'":""?>>Dr.</option>
             </select>
             
             
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
             <label>First Name <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
             
             <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"firstname" ,"id"=>"firstname","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 req","value"=>$row->firstname,"required"=>"required"))?>
             
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3"  >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
              <label>Middle Name</label>
              
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"middlename" ,"id"=>"sedang","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5","value"=>$row->middlename))?>
             
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
              <label class="">Last Name <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
              
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"lastname" ,"id"=>"lastname","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 req","value"=>$row->lastname,"required"=>"required"))?>
              </div>
            
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="row" >
           <div class="col-md-3"  >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
              <label  >Birthday <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
              
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"birthday" ,"id"=>"sedang","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 datepicker1 req","value"=>$row->birthday,"required"=>"required"))?>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
              <label  >Anniversary</label>
               <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"anniversary" ,"id"=>"lastname","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 datepicker1","value"=>$row->anniversary))?>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
             <label>Blood Group</label>
             <select name="blood_group"class="select2 form-control">
              
              <option value="A Positive" <?php if($row->blood_group=='A Positive') echo 'selected'; ?>>A Positive</option>
              <option value="A Negative" <?php if($row->blood_group=='A Negative') echo 'selected'; ?>>A Negative</option>
              
              <option value="B Positive" <?php if($row->blood_group=='B Positive') echo 'selected'; ?>>B Positive</option>
              <option value="B Negative" <?php if($row->blood_group=='B Negative') echo 'selected'; ?>>B Negative</option>
              
              <option value="AB Positive" <?php if($row->blood_group=='AB Positive') echo 'selected'; ?>>AB Positive</option>
              <option value="AB Negative" <?php if($row->blood_group=='AB Negative') echo 'selected'; ?>>AB Negative</option>
              
              <option value="O Positive" <?php if($row->blood_group=='O Positive') echo 'selected'; ?>>O Positive</option>
              <option value="O Negative" <?php if($row->blood_group=='O Negative') echo 'selected'; ?>>O Negative</option>
              
              <option value="Unknown" <?php if($row->blood_group=='Unknown') echo 'selected'; ?>>I Dont Know</option>
             </select>
             
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
             <label>Gender</label>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if($row->gender=='Male') echo 'checked'; ?>> Male</label>
             <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if($row->gender=='Female') echo 'checked'; ?>> Female</label>
            </div>
           </div>
           
          </div>
          <div class="row" >
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="control-group col-md-11">
             <label>Email <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
             <?php if($row->email=='') { ?>
             <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"email" ,"id"=>"email","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 req","value"=>$row->email,"required"=>"required"))?>
             
             <?php } else { ?>
             <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"email" ,"id"=>"email","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 req","value"=>$row->email,"readonly"=>"readonly"))?>
             
             <?php } ?>
             <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $row->email; ?>">
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
             <label  >Password <?php if($action == 'add') { ?><span class="req_star">*</span><?php } ?></label>
             <?php if($action == 'add') { ?>
             <?php echo form_password(array("name" =>"password" ,"id"=>"password","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5 req","value"=>$row->password)); ?>
             <?php } else { ?>
             <?php echo form_password(array("name" =>"" ,"id"=>"password","class"=>"m-wrap form-control col-md-5","value"=>$row->userdetail->userpass,"readonly"=>"readonly")); ?>
             <?php } ?>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          
          <div style="clear:both"></div>
          
           <div class="clearfix"></div><br>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
         
           <div class="col-md-5 profile-info">
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <h4>Permanent Address</h4>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Address <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls"> <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"paddress" ,"id"=>"","class"=>"m-wrap col-md-12 req form-control","style"=>"padding:2px;border:1px solid #ccc","value"=>$paddress->address," ","required"=>"required"))?> </div>
               
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class="control-group ">
               <label class="control-label">Country <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php 
                 $options = array();
                 $options['0']=BLANK_SELECT;
                 if(count($countries)){
                  foreach($countries as $val){
                   $options[$val->id]=$val->country;
                  }
                 }
                  
                 echo form_dropdown('pcountryid', $options, $paddress->countryid,'id="pcountryid" class="select2 req col-md-6 form-control" style="width:380px;" required');
                 echo form_hidden('originalstateid',$row->stateid);
                 echo form_hidden('originalcityid',$row->cityid);
                ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">State <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php 
               $options = array();
               $options['0']=BLANK_SELECT;
               
               if(count($states)){
                foreach($states as $val){
                 $options[$val->id]=$val->state;
                }
               }
               
               echo form_dropdown('pstateid', $options, $paddress->stateid,'id="pstateid"  class="col-md-6 req select2 form-control" required ');
               
              ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">City <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php 
                  $options = array();
               $options['0']=BLANK_SELECT;
               if(count($cities)){
                foreach($cities as $val){
                 $options[$val->id]=$val->city;
                }
               }
                 echo form_dropdown('pcityid', $options, $paddress->cityid,'id="pcityid" class="col-md-6 req select2 form-control" required ');
                 echo form_hidden('originalpstateid',$row->stateid);
                 echo form_hidden('originalpcityid',$paddress->cityid);
                ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>

             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Pin Code <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"ppincode" ,"id"=>"pincode","class"=>"m-wrap col-md-12 form-control req","value"=>$paddress->pincode," ","required"=>"required")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Phone1 <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"pphone1" ,"id"=>"pphone1","class"=>"phonevalid m-wrap col-md-12 form-control req","value"=>$paddress->phone1," ","required"=>"required")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Phone2 </label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"pphone2" ,"id"=>"pphone2","class"=>"phonevalid m-wrap col-md-12 form-control","value"=>$paddress->phone2," ")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Mobile <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"pmobile" ,"id"=>"pmobile","class"=>"phonevalid m-wrap col-md-12 form-control req","value"=>$paddress->mobile," ","required"=>"required")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             

          </div>
           <div class="col-md-5 profile-info pull-right">
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <h4>Correspondence Address</h4>
             
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Address <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls"> <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"caddress" ,"id"=>"","class"=>"m-wrap col-md-12 req form-control","style"=>"padding:2px;border:1px solid #ccc","value"=>$caddress->address," ","required"=>"required"))?> </div>
               
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class="control-group ">
               <label class="control-label">Country <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php 
                 $options = array();
                 $options['0']=BLANK_SELECT;
                 if(count($countries1)){
                  foreach($countries as $val){
                   $options[$val->id]=$val->country;
                  }
                 }
                 //echo $caddress->countryid;
                 echo form_dropdown('ccountryid', $options, $caddress->countryid,'id="countryid" class="select2 form-control req" style="width:380px;" required');
                 echo form_hidden('originalcstateid',$caddress->stateid);
                 echo form_hidden('originalccityid',$caddress->cityid);
                ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">State <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php 
               $options = array();
               $options['0']=BLANK_SELECT;
               if(count($states1)){
                foreach($states1 as $val){
                 $options[$val->id]=$val->state;
                }
               }
               echo form_dropdown('cstateid', $options, $caddress->stateid,'id="stateid"  class="col-md-6 select2 form-control req" required ');
               
              ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">City <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php 
                  $options = array();
               $options['0']=BLANK_SELECT;
               if(count($cities1)){
                foreach($cities1 as $val){
                 $options[$val->id]=$val->city;
                }
               }
                 echo form_dropdown('ccityid', $options, $caddress->cityid,'id="cityid" class="col-md-6 select2 req form-control" required');
                 echo form_hidden('originalcstateid',$caddress->stateid);
                 echo form_hidden('originalccityid',$caddress->cityid);
                ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>

             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Pin Code <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"pincode" ,"id"=>"pincode","class"=>"m-wrap col-md-12 form-control req","value"=>$caddress->pincode," ","required"=>"required")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Phone1 <span class="req_star">*</span> </label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"cphone1" ,"id"=>"cphone1","class"=>"phonevalid m-wrap col-md-12 form-control req","value"=>$caddress->phone1," ","required"=>"required")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Phone2 </label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"cphone2" ,"id"=>"cphone2","class"=>"phonevalid m-wrap col-md-12 form-control","value"=>$caddress->phone2," ")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class=" control-group col-md-11">
               <label class="control-label">Mobile <span class="req_star">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"cmobile" ,"id"=>"cmobile","class"=>"phonevalid m-wrap col-md-12 form-control req","value"=>$caddress->mobile," ","required"=>"required")); ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             
             
             <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#countryid").trigger("change");
              });
             </script>
             <div class="clearfix"></div><br>
             
          </div>
        </div>
        
         </div>
```

```html
<div class="submit-btn pull-right">
         <?php 
         echo form_hidden('action',$action);
         echo form_hidden('id',$id);
         ?>
         
         <input type="button" id="submituserform"   value="Submit" class="btn-info btn button btnNext"></input>
       </div>
```

I am only enclosing part of my view code as it is large.

Tried Changing **config.php** to

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].':8080/Jan182017';`

but results in the url - http://localhost/Jan182017/users/add_user/#menu1 and all the UI gets distorted. All i want to do is to add **:8080** to **localhost** on every submit and button click in a codeigniter application without affecting UI of the application.

Comment: I'm not able to test at the moment, but can you try:

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/Jan182017/';`

Comment: tried this still redirects to http://localhost/Jan182017/users/add_user/#menu1

Comment: Use `$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost:8080/Jan182017/";`

Comment: You could potentially add a Virtual Host alternatively..

Comment: @shihas same result http://localhost/Jan182017, port number missing

Comment: @JonathanClark , tried adding virtual Host but does not seem to work

Comment: Maybe .htaccess problem?

Comment: My .htacces looks like this @JonathanClark <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @JonathanClark , I somehow think u are right

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Listen "8080" port in

> command : vim /etc/apache2/appache2.conf file

then restart the apache2

> service : Command : apache2 service restart

Then you will be able to open the port for that and then gave permission to the root folder

> Controller folder : $this->current_module = $this->uri->segment(2);
>
> View : form_open('', array('id' => 'add_template', 'autocomplete' => 'off'));

After submit the form it should redirect to the

> redirect(base_url('admin/' . $this->current_module));

Please check it.